# how do i apply class properties using addClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am using jQuery addClass function in my script. using the chrome debugger i can see that is does work and the new class has been added to my element.
I have also given unique properties to that new class in the css file, so I expected the new proparties to overwrite the old ones = yet it does'nt do that.

A small example - at the original class my element has a z-index of 1; at the new class, it suppose to have a z-index of 3; yet even though i can see it has both the old and new class once i click it - it stays with a z-index of 1;

Can anyone please help?
thank you!

Comment: can you show some code html/js/css.?

Comment: The browser developer tools have a whole elaborate set of tools for analyzing how an element's style is determined. Have you tried that?

Comment: try on these lines `$('yourElement').removeClass('someClass').addClass('someOtherClass');`

Comment: Thanks., but i want both classes to be implemented on this element

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because both classes have same property i.e. `z-index`. Whichever class is between old and new is written last in the `css` file would be applicable.

Either remove old class and add new class or write `!important` after second class.

Example:

```
.old{z-index:1;}
.new{z-index:3 !important;}
```

OR:

```
$(element).toggleClass("old new");//it will remove old class and add new
```

Comment: need a clarification . If !important is used , won't it make sure that the style always remains even though you add another class ?

Comment: So, will removing .new and adding .old remove the z-index:3 and make it z-index:1 or will it be stuck on z-index:3

Comment: @harsha absolutely no.

Comment: removing `.new` and adding `.old` will make `z-index:1` because `.new` is removed, hence, all properties associated with `.new` will also be not applicable.

Comment: thanks, i tried it, but it still won't work... :(
it does'nt look like the new proparty is overWriten, but as if it does'nt even exist.